# Throttling a Web Socket in Java

Tags: java, rest, websocket, jboss, throttling

In our company, we are developing a brokerage web-based application in which customers can log in from client product and place order requests to the server. 
The server has both WebSocket and rest endpoints. Further, it is deployed in JBOSS container. client applications push orders via WebSocket to the server at a high rate (approximately ~5000 requests per second).
And other inquiry services such as login/buying power validations are provided through rest services.

The complication arose when we were having a load test in different environments. We logged into the server via client product and push order requests at high rate via web socket, 
at the same time we tried to log into the server with another client product. But all of sudden rest API became overwhelmed and unresponsive. 
The server only prioritized on processing order requests but failed in response to a login request. Recommendations are highly appreciated in this scenario. 
Are there any throttling mechanism available for JBOSS container or does precaution should be taken at the application level?

Comment: Did you try taking thread dump? It would give you a fair idea.

Comment: I didn't since this works well in high-end servers only fail in servers with low specifications. So I believe this requires a mechanism like throttling to limit order request rates, does it? Any idea about limit request rate in web socket or any way to manage it through JBOSS container?

Comment: I am not aware of such rate limiting at JBOSS container but yes, you can actually do a benchmarking for different hardware sizes. You can categorise the hardware under say, Small,Medium,Large or Extra Large and define a  threshold for them as a part of performance/load testing. The rate limiter can be written as a generic code which will be executed before the actual business logic like some filters. This you can make it as a platform utility.

Comment: You mean adding proxy or Control rate through application ??

Comment: Yeah. I meant somewhat same